# typedDataSet activate query C#

Tags: c#, typed-dataset

I have a `TypedDataSet` object. and i have a query `"select name from t_table where name LIKE '%(text from user)';` how can i insert this query into the data set and activate it on t_table?  i need to get a text from the user and activate the query by what he gave me. how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want a benefit of types dataset then you have to add table to the designer other wise it would be complex to do same thing by coding IMO.

Follow [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320714) instructions to use typed dataset.

---

[image]

I just added one more query with where clause, 
Now you need to just call

```
Adapter.FillByName(tablename,value of parameter)
```

Comment: is there no other way to write it so it would be simpler? just to add a query and activate it...

Comment: it's not doing  what i ment. i edited my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: If you working with designer then you can add a query with where clause and respective parameters. I post one screenshot, let me know if you looking something like this..

Comment: yes. somthing like that. can you write all the query here? how do i add the query, and how do i tell it what parameters it gets? and in your example "FillByName" is the query, it's not suppose to be activated from the table? like: Adapter.Table2.FillByName(tablename,value of parameter)

Comment: Just right click on adapter and say add query then you will get complete query window, you will see the filter column thr that is what u need to use to set parameter. Or at query window write your query and for where clause write the parameter like @Name. Like Select * from emp where name =@name. And lastly you have to use adapter.fillbyname() and for that you need to create adapter instance and then further use it.

Comment: how do i create this adapter? it's not suppose to be activated from the dataSet object?

Comment: At first I thought you want to add custom queries to adapter so I posted something for that, anyway thats great you achieved what you trying.